# Filemaker GetSummary from related table

Tags: filemaker

I'm been using FM for the first time and have a need to use Get Summary on a financial information table.  This generates various summaries of different income by customer, year and type.  The layout generated from this table is good.  The use of Get Summary allows me to do math with the various results, whereas sub summary totals by income type (as far as I know) cannot be added and divided by each other.

The problem I'm facing is that I wish now to create a layout based on customers and include some of the Get Summary detail from the financial table.  Because my new layout is based on customers, I understand I cannot use Get Summary from financial as either a related field or in a portal.

The end game is simply to scroll through customer records, one after the other, and have key financial information show on their 'home' screen if you will, for years and type.

Any help gratefully appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand I cannot use Get Summary from financial as either a
>   related field or in a portal.

No, that's not quite correct. The GetSummary() function returns the sub-summary value by breakfield - **if** records are sorted by breakfield. Thus if the portal (or the underlying relationship) sorts the related records by type, you *will* see sub-summary values in the portal. However, you won't be able to see **only** sub-summary values, since a portal has no sub-summary parts.

There are other ways to show summarized related data. If you don't have (and don't expect to have) a large amount of records, considering filtering a (one-row) portal to show only a specific type of related records, then place the summary field inside it. Of course, this assumes the types are known in advance and unchanging.

Comment: Michael, thanks for this, really helpful in what I'm doing at the moment :)